# Spring boot login failure

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to spring and have been following along with a few tutorials online. I have created an app which contains a login using username and password. Now everything was working fine at the start but as I have continued to work on the app it has started to fail at login giving a null pointer issue but not giving any specifics. This happened once or twice at the beginning, but is getting continually worse to the point it now takes 7 or 8 restarts of the app before it lets me login. The app starts fine but as soon as I enter a username and password it crashes out.

I am using a h2 database for testing which I have populated with test users and data. If there is anyone that could help in this matter or point me in the right direction it would be great. Below is my files and the Stacktrace.  If there are any other files that you think I should add to help get an answer leave a comment and I will add them.

My properties file.

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console
spring.datasource.platform=h2
```

My IndexController

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/access_denied")
    public String notAuth() {
        return "access_denied";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginForm() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/logout")
    public String logout() {
        return "login";
    }

}
```

My WebSecurity configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("daoAuthenticationProvider")
    public void setAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider     authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor) {
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new PasswordEncoder();
        passwordEncoder.setPasswordEncryptor(passwordEncryptor);
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                                           UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new  DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
          authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().headers().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index", "/**/favicon.ico") .permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/companies/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/expenses/new", "/expenses/edit/**", "expenses/save")
            .hasAnyRole("ADMIN, MANAGER")
            .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/expenses/list", "/expenses/**")
            .hasAnyRole("ADMIN, MANAGER, WORKER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied");
   }
}
```

This is the UserDetailsImpl

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Boolean enabled = true;

    public void setAuthorities(Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

SpringUserDetialsImpl which uses a converter in conjunction with User class

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class SpringUserDetailsImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserService userService;
    private Converter<User, UserDetails> userUserDetailsConverter;

    private static final Logger logger =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringUserDetailsImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {

        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "userToUserDetails")
    public void setUserUserDetailsConverter(Converter<User, UserDetails> userUserDetailsConverter) {

        this.userUserDetailsConverter = userUserDetailsConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        logger.info(String.format("User %s was found", userService.findByUsername(username).getUsername()));
        return userUserDetailsConverter.convert(userService.findByUsername(username));
    }
}
```

And the converter class

```
@Component
public class UserToUserDetails implements Converter<User, UserDetails> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserToUserDetails.class);

    @Override
    public UserDetails convert(User user) {

        UserDetailsImpl userDetails = new UserDetailsImpl();

        if (user != null) {

            userDetails.setId(user.getId());
            userDetails.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            userDetails.setPassword(user.getEncryptedPassword());
            userDetails.setEnabled(user.getValid());

            Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

            user.getRoles().forEach(role -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole())));

            userDetails.setAuthorities(authorities);

            logger.info(String.format("User details %s", userDetails.getUsername()));

            return userDetails;
        } else {

            System.out.print("This is an issue");
            return userDetails;
        }
    }
}
```

And the stacktrace

```
2017-02-12 21:30:49.807 ERROR 15146 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:164) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: Please show your UserDetailsService or publish whole application on github maybe?

Comment: Change(Autowire) to `@Autowired private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;`

Comment: @PrasannaKumar for some strange reason you are right adding     '@Autowired' to the AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider variable seems to be working. I thought with Spring the correct protocol was to either use a setter or constructor for dependence.  If you would like to give a full answer and a bit of explanation I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add `@Autowired` to  `authenticationProvider;`

**[@Autowired](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)** *Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.*

When you want to use it as *Spring bean* you need to Autowire the bean.It can be used on

- **Setter method**

  `@Autowired
  public void setSpellChecker( SpellChecker spellChecker ){
    this.spellChecker = spellChecker;
  }`
- **Constructor**

  `@Autowired
   public TextEditor(SpellChecker spellChecker){
      System.out.println("Inside TextEditor constructor." );
      this.spellChecker = spellChecker;
   }`
- **Properties**, in your case it is on properties.

  `@Autowired
  private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;`